How to step into COM object when debugging in Qt Creator?
I have a COM dll and an app using that COM. When debugging the app, I cannot step into the code of the COM despite the fact that both the COM and the app are of debug version. For example, the following is a piece of code of the app.
long QAxBase::queryInterface(const QUuid &uuid, void **iface) const
{
    *iface = 0;
    if (!d->ptr) {
        ((QAxBase*)this)->initialize(&d->ptr);
        d->initialized = true;
    }

    if (d->ptr && !uuid.isNull())
        return d->ptr->QueryInterface(uuid, iface);

    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

When it stops at the line
return d->ptr->QueryInterface(uuid, iface);

I press F11 and suppose it will step into the QueryInterface function of the COM but it won't, it just goes to the next line as if I pressed F10.
